# Laravel pagination shows a link for every page

Tags: laravel, pagination

With the help of some research I have done on the Web, I have created a function for creating a custom pagination in Laravel. Here's the code:

```
    protected function customPaginator($array, $page) {
        $paginator = $array;
        $perPage = $this->itemsPerPage;   
        if ($page > count($paginator) or $page < 1) { $page = 1; }
        $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;
        $array = array_slice($paginator,$offset,$perPage);
        return Paginator::make($array, count($paginator), $perPage);        
    }
```

The code works just fine, but it shows a link for every page. I would like it to show ellipsis or something like that instead if there are many pages for pagination. Something like this:
<< 1 2 ... 5 6 >>

How would you do that in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom presenter to achieve this. Just look at Laravel's Pagination Presenter class and extend it to create your custom presenter.

[Presenter Abstract Class](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/Presenter.php) and [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#custom-presenters)

After this you need to configure the view from config/view.php by default it is slider-3.